# ISC DHCP Spamming /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, dhcp, syslog

I recently setup a Linux box to run a DHCP server. One of the prerequisites was to get all of its log messages onto a specific file outside of the /var/log folder. For that purpose, I inserted the line

```
log-facility local6;
```

On my DHCP server's configuration file. Thanks to this, almost all of the logging messages are being channeled into the local6 syslog facility. To get these messages into the desired file, I added/changed the following in the rsyslog.conf file:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local6.none   /var/log/messages
local6.*   /srv/cluster/dhcpd/dhcpd.log
```

However, there's just one message that keeps getting spammed into /var/log/messages, and that is a version message that DHCP repeats every 10 seconds. I have no idea why this is happening. Thus, I ask: what can I do to stop DHCP from repeatedly printing a version message to /var/log/messages every 10 seconds?

Comment: As far as I know, the ISC DHCPd only prints the version number when it starts. Have you checked that it is not restarting every 10 seconds, possibly because of a configuration issue?

Comment: Very unlikely, but will check it out.

Comment: DHCP is not stopping and starting every 10 seconds. The dhcpd.log file only has the opening messages (about its interface and zones) printed whenever I restart the service manually. However, for some reason, the execution time that shows up on top and ps is always equal to zero minutes.

Comment: Can you specify what is the version number message you get?

Comment: The time staying at zero is correct - that's the amount of CPU time that has been used by the daemon and that'll always be very little.

Comment: @Vojtech The message version is the following: `Nov 11 12:40:43 centos2 dhcpd: isc-dhcpd-4.2.5`.

Comment: I checked the sources. That message is only ever logged by dhcpd when it's run with the "--version" command line argument. It exits immediately after printing that message. Something is calling that every 10 seconds on your system.

Comment: This is incredibly odd. Is there a way to see where a service is being spawned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31420/discussion-between-vojtech-and-lopson).

Comment: The easiest way I can come up with is to replace the dhcpd binary with a script that logs the command line, time and output of 'ps axuf' to a file under /tmp and then calls dhcpd with the original arguments.

Comment: +1 not so much for the question, but for the underlying configuration of the dhcpd.conf to hide the bulk of the logs.